# Confidence intervals for series of Covid tests

Tags: confidence-interval, sensitivity-specificity

Suppose I take two antigen tests and each test has a specificity of 75.3% (95% confidence interval from 65.8% to 83.4%) e.g. from https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/33455451/

**A. what is the sensitivity of the two tests together?**

Taking the equation off of https://radiopaedia.org/articles/sensitivity-and-specificity-of-multiple-tests

Combined sensitivity: (A)sen + [1 - (A)sen] x (B)sen

That would be 93.9%.

**B. But what would I do with the confidence interval? Is it the same calculation?**

That would give me 88.3 to 97.2%…
Is the correct way to calculate the confidence interval of the combined test?

**C. In layman's terms...** If I test negative both times, would I say that I am 95% confident that the result is at least 88.3% sensitive?

Answer (score 3):

Let's begin with assuming the two tests are independent of one another (maybe run by a different lab, with reactants sourced from different companies, etc etc).

**Sensitivity** as a probabilistic concept is the probability you test positive given you have the disease, $P(T+ \vert D+)=p$.  I suppose the sensitivity of taking two tests is the probability *at least one test is positive* given you are disease positive.  If $p$ is the sensitivity of both tests, then the probability at least one is positive out of 2 is $2p(1-p) + p^2 = 2p - p^2$, which agrees with what you have presented.

As for the confidence interval, you *could* use the Delta method. The Delta method states that

$$ \operatorname{Var}(g(X)) = [g'(X)]^2 \operatorname{Var}(X) $$

Here, $g(x) = 2x - x^2$.  Some alegbra yields...

$$ \operatorname{Var}(2p-p^2) = [2-2p]^2 \operatorname{Var}(p) = \sigma^2 $$

Here, $\operatorname{Var}(p)$ would be whatever was reported as the variance for the sensitivity in the paper you linked. The last step is to take your estimate and add/substract two standard deviations (square root of the quantity obtained from the delta method).  Note that use of the Delta Method assumes asymptotic normality of the statistic of interest.